# How to Customize the full text search function provided by postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to customize the postgresql full text search functionality so that

For example, I can enter "Stouffers" and get a match on Stouffer's frozen foods.  If I leave off one of the "f"s and spell it "Stoufers" I don't get a match.  That's one of the things that the customized text search is supposed to handle.  It converts all the text into a phonetic type code and searches on that.

Please help me in this how i can achive that. 
i found some help that i need to write a custom parser in C for doing this but i am very poor in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or get a standalone search engine such as Solr or Xapian with stemming, spelling, phonetic etc.
[Django-haystack](http://haystacksearch.org) brings you both of them.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try using the [ISpell](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-ISPELL-DICTIONARY) dictionary for postgresql or [Tsearch2](http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/postgres/gist/tsearch/V2/) which has some [spelling correction module](http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/postgres/gist/pg_trgm/README.pg_trgm).